# How can I convert an object into an anonymously-typed object with the same properties and data?

Tags: c#, type-conversion, anonymous-types

If I have a class like:

```
public class Customer
{ 
    public string Name { get; set; } 
}
```

How can I convert an object of this class:

```
var cust = new Customer { Name = "Test" };
```

into something like:

```
new { Name = "Test" }
```

Comment: What? Have you seen any think in C# like what you are asking. `new { Name = "Test" };`

Comment: You cannot convert between those types because they are not type compatible, the best you can do is : var x = new { cust.Name }

Comment: Why would you WANT to do this?  If you have a strongly-typed object why on earth would you want to give it up for a non-portable anonymous type?

Comment: The reason you're looking for this can certainly help us find you the best solution. Are you thinking of doing some ad-hoc "inheritance" where you add properties to an existing type? Are you passing this on to code that uses reflection? In any case I can (currently) think of, passing a `Customer` will do the same as passing an anonymous type. Please elaborate.

Answer (score 2):

Since anonymous types — `new { … }` — do not have a name, there is no way how you can achieve what you want through an explicit type cast — `(TypeName)value`. There are also no implicit type casts available, so you will actually have to create a property-by-property copy:

```
var customer = new Customer { Name = "Joe" };
var anonymous = new { customer.Name };
```

(Note the abbreviated syntax in the second line of code: You do not have to write `Name = customer.Name`; `customer.Name` is enough for the compiler to infer that there should be a property `Name`.)

Comment: not sure what's with the negative vote this looks like a good answer given the limited information.

Comment: yeah I agree, I've deleted the answer.